# Problem creating another ingress-nginx/ingress-nginx via helm "Error: rendered manifests contain a resource that already exists"

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-helm, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

I keep getting this error or variations when I try to do as it asks:

```
Error: rendered manifests contain a resource that already exists. Unable to continue with install: IngressClass "nginx" in namespace "" exists and cannot be imported into the current release: invalid ownership metadata; annotation validation error: key "meta.helm.sh/release-name" must equal "new-ingress-nginx": current value is "old-ingress-nginx"
```

I'm using helm to install:

```
helm repo add ingress-nginx https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx
helm repo update

helm install new-ingress-nginx ingress-nginx/ingress-nginx --set-string controller.podAnnotations."app\.kubernetes\.io/instance"="new"
```

I've tried with and without the podAnnotations as I found a post mentioning to try that.

I'm using google kubernetes engine and what I have done is merged all my api's under one load balancer/ingress-nginx but I would like to figure out the issue.

Comment: Maybe [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61349161/helm-error-upgrade-failed-rendered-manifests-contain-a-new-resource-that-alrea?rq=1) can help you.

Comment: @NadiaEspinosa it helped me get to the answer, thank you.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I was able to solve my problem after reading through [this on github](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/issues/6100)

[Some changes were made](https://kubernetes.io/blog/2020/04/02/improvements-to-the-ingress-api-in-kubernetes-1.18/) and `--set controller.ingressClassResource.name=<somename>` is now used and the yaml file no longer looks like:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: some-ingress
  namespace: somenamespace
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: <somename>
    ...
spec:
  tls:
  ...
```

it looks like:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: some-ingress
  namespace: somenamespace
  annotations:
    ...
spec:
  ingressClassName: <somename>
  tls:
  ...
```

Answer (score 6):

If there is an existing ingress class resource with the same name eg:- nginx. Then delete the resource as shown below.

search ingressClasses

```
kubectl get ingressClasses
```

Delete the nginx ingressClass

```
kubectl delete ingressClasses nginx
```